# How do I manipulate account balance in an investment web application with NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on an investment web application project using NodeJS and MongoDB. I already work on the part of allowing users to make an investment but I don't know how to go about the account balance section. After the user invests, the account balance should update after 3 days.

Here is a simple maths behind my description above:

1. User invests $200.
2. After 3 days, the user gains 10% of what he invested - $220
3. On the third day, account balance change from 0 to 220.

Is this possible with NodeJs, if yes, how do I go about it?

Comment: What Are you tryna essentially do? Wouldn't that require polling? i.e. constantly checking for changes

Comment: If a user is investing certain amount, you must be keeping this information in your database. I would suggest using a sql trigger, which will trigger after 3 days and update that amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply run a cron job that is executing every 3rd day an mongodb query

Here cron job for node.js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

```
var cron = require('node-cron');
 

cron.schedule('0 0 */3 * *', () => {
  // this function is gonna be executed every 3rd day at midnight
  Model.update({ ... })
});
```

https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*/3_*_*

> At 00:00 on every 3rd day-of-month.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This was really helpful

Comment: @Danicoco i am glad i could help you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the account balance. Just store invested amount that user has invested on particular day. And then, whenever you need to know the balance just calculate it by calculating the difference time from now.

Company policy could be to recalculate the balance by then end of month, 3-months, 6-months or yearly. And in that day, you could update the account balance and update the date as well.

So, you can have:

```
invested_day, capitalized_day, account_balance
```

Google about cron-job, you'll need it to update store on the scheduled date.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is **store date of investment** to database and whenever user visits the application **show him loader and get system's current date and compare it to stored date using moment or yourself** if difference is of 3 days then update date and amount both.
But what if user visits **after 9 day or 10 days** then keep in mind calculate days in multiple of three and increase amount accordingly.
Also keep in mind **timezone of server and client may be different** so also take care of it.